# Set input text box to data then submit to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Basically i have a textbox on my .html page

```
<input name="points" type="text" id="points" value=""/>
```

and in the .js that gets called just onsubmit

```
document.getElementById('points').value = creator.showData();
```

i actually see with my eyes that the text is being added to the textbox however the php isn't reading the $_POST however if i manually enter the text into the same text box it works.

Any Ideas ? been screwing with my head all morning XD

Comment: Maybe `showData` is adding blank spaces thus although it look numeric it isn't?

Comment: the same thing happen with me, but i was using java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably submits the form before the value is set.

Try this...

```
(function() {    
    var submitted = false;
    form.onsubmit = function(event) {
        if (submitted) {
            return true;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('points').value = creator.showData();
        submitted = true;
        form.submit();
    }
})();
```